# Cannot find method setActiveSheet(string)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, which runs on JavaScript, I'm getting this message, "Cannot find method setActiveSheet(string). (line 4, file "Code")", I don't know why... I'm pretty new to coding, so bear with me.

```
function onOpen() {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var sheet = email.slice(0,-11);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the "Cannot find method" error because the setActiveSheet() method takes an argument of type Sheet, not a string.  See the specification here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setActiveSheet(Sheet)

In order to get a Sheet object from the string, you need to open the parent Spreadsheet, then get the appropriate sheet by name, then you can pass it to setActiveSheet.

Assuming this script is embedded in the relevant Spreadsheet, that looks like this:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet));
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, happy coding!

Comment: Such a lifesaver with this answer, saved me a big headache. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me.

```
function theSecondSheet() {
   var activeSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    if(activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2").activate()){
     SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(activeSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2"));
    }
}
```